# Strange flow for seekBar on Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media

I use MediaPlayer for playing a single MP3 song from network. Data source is the file downloaded from network. This files comes in chuncks.

Let's assume we have following playing state.

Song duration: 4:00

Current chunck loaded in player: 1:00

Let's say I want to skip some part of a song and seek forward. I do it with MediaPlayer.seekTo() method. If I seek to position (1:40) it is not performed correctly, seek bar goes at start position (00:00) and the playerr stops.

```
public static void seekTo(int progress) {
try {
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(sFilePath);
    mp.prepare();
    int offset = (progress * mp.getDuration()) / 100;

    if (sCompleted)
        return;
    sLastSeek = offset;

    if (offset > sMediaPlayer.getDuration()) {
        sMediaPlayer.reset();
        sMediaPlayer.setDataSource(sFilePath);
        sMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();


    } else {
        sMediaPlayer.seekTo(offset);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4124 there is a bug that was fixed in 2.2 - see if your situation is similar .

Comment: i have saw that problem, situation is similar, but i use android 4.0, testing device also android 4.0